# Internal Server Error only on frontend and certain admin pages

Tags: errors, server, internal-server-error

I'm experiencing an internal server error on a site, but only on the publicly facing site, and on certain pages in the admin section, including posts (`/wp-admin/edit.php`) and anything else accessing `/wp-admin/edit.php` (e.g. pages and custom post types), and media (`/wp-admin/upload.php`). Every other admin page seems to work properly.

I realize this is likely a server issue, but it's so strange (some pages are fine, others not), that I thought it would be worth asking about. I've deactivated all plugins and checked the `error_log` files (especially in /wp-admin), but haven't found anything. I should also note that I'm seeing [core dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) files written to the server each time a page returns an error, but I'm not sure how/if I can analyze those.

This did happen after attempting to move the site to a different domain, if that helps. I believe I did everything correctly, but it's possible (and even likely, given the problem) that I didn't.

Comment: I get this too. Are you by chance using GoDaddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get internal server errors quite often in my everyday coding work if i misspell PHP function names in my code. So try deactivating your plugins and re-enabling one by one.

Comment: I had disabled all of my plugins, but thanks to your suggestion, I temporarily renamed my functions.php file, and that fixed it. I didn't realize a problem in that file (or a plugin) would have that kind of effect. Thanks!

Comment: Yepp, it's a bit weird...i think I'm only getting them ever since i upgraded to PHP 5.3, which was also the moment i changed some stuff in my php.ini, so it could be either one. Before that, i'd simply get the usual PHP error output. Could be that i deactivated that, so PHP now causes the server itself to through the exception (would be somewhat logical).

Answer (score 0):

I used to have those exact problems problems. At first I thought it was my host (godaddy)... I was kind of right. I don;t know what OS you have but, everything was fixed when I switched from windows to linux. I guess WP agrees more w/ linux.